# Slow boot on Fedora 24, possibly caused by plymouth-quit-wait.service

Tags: fedora, boot, plymouth

So I've been using Fedora 24 for about two weeks now and the one thing that bothers me is the *really* long time it takes to boot. I've been trying to investigate this via `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame` and it seems there are some startup services that take quite a long time, mostly the `plymouth-quit-wait.service`. Since I'm still very new to Linux, I can't decide whether that service is the actual cause or whether it just has to wait for something else to happen.
I don't know if that's relevant, however I'm using the Workstation edition of Fedora 24 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X220 with an i5-2540M CPU.
I'll append the output of `systemd-analyze`, `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical chain` to this question.

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2.546s (kernel) + 4.697s (initrd) + 1min 33.630s (userspace) = 1min 40.874s


systemd-analyze blame
     49.647s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     28.356s dnf-makecache.service
     13.163s systemd-journal-flush.service
     12.147s firewalld.service
     11.119s systemd-udev-settle.service
      9.478s dev-mapper-fedora\x2droot.device
      7.549s libvirtd.service
      5.923s udisks2.service
      5.694s abrtd.service
      5.658s accounts-daemon.service
      5.312s chronyd.service
      4.585s polkit.service
      3.809s lvm2-pvscan@8:2.service
      3.594s unbound-anchor.service
      2.736s ModemManager.service
      2.430s proc-fs-nfsd.mount
      2.367s lvm2-monitor.service
      2.287s cups.service
      2.283s dmraid-activation.service
      2.121s systemd-rfkill.service
      2.053s plymouth-start.service
      2.033s systemd-logind.service
      2.014s gssproxy.service
      1.873s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.830s packagekit.service
      1.803s rtkit-daemon.service
      1.794s NetworkManager.service
      1.792s avahi-daemon.service
      1.700s systemd-udevd.service
      1.678s bluetooth.service
      1.423s fedora-readonly.service
      1.367s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
      1.161s abrt-ccpp.service
      1.095s wpa_supplicant.service
       972ms gdm.service
       798ms systemd-journald.service
       795ms dev-mqueue.mount
       790ms upower.service
       738ms systemd-random-seed.service
       734ms user@42.service
       695ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bc0eb656\x2d624f\x2d4c3d\x2d90a3\x2d321abc24867b.service
       694ms systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-fedora\x2dhome.service
       684ms auditd.service
       656ms tmp.mount
       621ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       521ms systemd-sysctl.service
       479ms fedora-import-state.service
       438ms rpc-statd-notify.service
       395ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       364ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
       356ms dev-hugepages.mount
       319ms home.mount
       299ms systemd-fsck-root.service
       280ms dracut-shutdown.service
       254ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       232ms boot.mount
       230ms plymouth-read-write.service
       226ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       222ms colord.service
       163ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       149ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       136ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       132ms nfs-config.service
        89ms user@1000.service
        87ms blk-availability.service
        76ms dev-mapper-fedora\x2dswap.swap
        73ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
        70ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        28ms livesys.service
        15ms livesys-late.service
         9ms var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount
         6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms sys-kernel-config.mount

systemd-analyze critical chain
graphical.target @1min 33.616s
└─multi-user.target @1min 33.616s
  └─libvirtd.service @37.051s +7.549s
    └─remote-fs.target @36.969s
      └─remote-fs-pre.target @36.969s
        └─iscsi-shutdown.service @36.965s
          └─network.target @36.933s
           └─wpa_supplicant.service @39.880s +1.095s
            └─dbus.service @21.045s
             └─basic.target @20.963s
              └─sockets.target @20.963s
                └─dbus.socket @20.963s
                  └─sysinit.target @20.911s
                    └─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount @1min 32.526s +5ms
                      └─system.slice
                        └─-.slice
```

Answer (score 1):

the `plymouth-quit-wait.service` is just what you see on your screen, while the other services are starting. It is just passively waiting for the other services, that take too long. I would blame `dnf-makecache`, `systemd-journal-flush` and `firewalld` (do you need them? Why do they take so long?)

Answer (score 0):

I just read about `dnf-makecache` and `systemd-journal-flush` and decided to disable them; don't think I need those. I'm not sure about FirewallD, however. Is there a faster alternative?
I can't tell why they're taking so long, but I guess disabling these two will make it a lot faster.